# What is the goal of MSE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing

**What is the goal of MSE? Is it to get a repository of interesting questions and well-written answers. Or are we instead an online math tutoring site where we help anyone as long as they seem to be trying. These two goals are often in contradiction with each other!**

I am afraid that we are headed in the direction of being an online tutoring site, at least for a couple months in the spring and fall when school is in session. What I have noticed this past spring was that MSE was inundated with "newbie" users coming on here and asking on average a high volume of problem-set questions each--oftentimes 10 questions/week per person. Now, in all fairness, the users were demonstrating some effort in their questions. But it was clear that they were struggling with the basics, so their questions were hardly what you would consider to be "good" questions. And yet, these users still received a lot of help on their questions from the more established posters on MSE nonetheless. And so it continued on through March and April. It is like MSE was filling the role of Teaching Assistant or whatever for these students.

[It seems to have quieted down now that the most recent semester is about to end, but it will pick up again. Just wait until the fall! Or maybe even later this summer. If not even sooner than that.]

If the desire is to move back away from being a homework-tutoring site, it is probably going to be hard for the site to stop this without making changes on the admin level. [A possibility would be lowering the number of votes to close from 5 to 3. Another possibility would be to make a tag or section of MSE dedicated for someone learning the basics.] **Meanwhile, I'm not seeing how the EoQS currently implemented, is changing this.** This site is nonetheless being clogged with many boring or poorly-written questions, which are still getting rewarded with a long string of comments doing their best to tutor the student, and at least one of those comments [are comments under the purview of EoQS$^1$] has the answer to the student's questions. These questions may get a couple votes to close and maybe a downvote too, but then they also get a pity upvote. And so we get many more such questions, because users are being rewarded for asking them--whether there is an "Answer" or not. There does seem to be a critical mass of users on MSE who do feel that this should be a site where struggling students can come for help with their basic homework even if their questions don't meet the MSE Guidelines, as long as they are demonstrating some effort.

If you cannot already tell, my vote would be MSE moving towards a repository of high-quality questions and answers, and away from being a homework-tutoring site.

**ETA: In any event though, I do think EoQS would work better if the way it were administered were shifted.** What if the following changes were implemented:

(a) Reduce the number of votes needed to *close* [**NOT** delete!] a question from 5 down to 4 or 3. I think a reason why EoQS came to be in the first place was the proliferation of too many really bad questions that get too much oxygen.

(b) Enforce *comments* as much as answers. In particular, no more rewarding bad questions by answering in the comments. If we don't want a bad question answered in the answer box, then we don't want a bad question answered in the comments either. Likewise, if a question is worth keeping around, then it is worth being answered, *in the answer box*, as answering in the comments really helps no one.

I'm not necessarily for more enforcement, I am for smarter enforcement. The net result of what we are doing now w EoQS are question after question of debatable quality, with a long string of comments--in place of a well-written answer written where it is supposed to be--the answer box. The worst of both worlds--still no quality control but now messy flow. Should those questions be allowed to stay? Maybe. I get from the comments and whatnot that it is a debate. But if so, then at the very least, the formatting should be right.

Please advise.

**ETA 5/20/2022 18:30 EDT: Reading the other posts and comments here, I think the biggest problem with EoQS as I see it, is in unclear and contradictory objectives of here, and so what gets enforced as bad content is often absurd.** I understand that really confused students are going to end up asking questions that are really duplicates [even with context]. For example, every semester we see a bunch of question such as:

*Is $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2; 2x_1+x_2=5\}$ a vector space?*

We will also get a bunch of questions about the probability of drawing $2$ red cards or a certain hand from a deck of $52$ cards, and so on. Just as we did last semester and the semester before that. The consensus on here, going by what I'm reading in the comments anyway, is that those questions should get respect on here if the student is showing effort. Alright, fine and great. If this is what the board decides then let's give those questions respect.
**But then if these questions are fine and allowed, then what is the point of EoQS again? What is the point of shutting down more interesting questions again then? Sometimes an answer to a duplicate gives a different take that may be useful to the next person. And just as much, why are the ones who *answer* a lot of hard questions getting put into the corner then. They are the ones contributing to the knowledge base here! And they were never really contributing to the problem EoQS was supposedly about fixing.**

It often just all seems to arbitrary and capricious....

$^1$ **EoQS = Enforcement of Quality Standards**

Comment: @amWhy I do my best to vote to close questions. I suppose moving forward I will flag more. But I do wager that it would also be necessary to (a) require only 3 votes to close questions (b) extend EoQS to *comments* that answer bad questions.

Comment: @littleO  Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/9003

Comment: @Mike IMHO that's a false dichotomy between "*repository of high-quality questions and answers*" vs. "*a homework-tutoring site*". I see it closer to "*repository of (random) knowledge*" vs. "*museum of (curated) pieces of math arts*" as I wrote [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34428/291201). There are questions asked on MSE with appealing, non-trivial math contents, but which get summarily dismissed because they don't raise to the level of "*high-quality questions*" in EoQS' eyes.

Comment: (...) Which btw is why I think lowering the close vote-count may not be such a good idea. Many (most?) "*low quality*" questions get closed and deleted before the OP has a chance to even see the votes and ammend their question.

Comment: (...) Back to the question of "*what is the goal of MSE*" one other and often overlooked goal is simply staying operational. Without being privy to their internal workings, but this is usually driven by traffic. Seems odd, for example, that 3rd party approach0.xyz is able to find related questions and duplicates that MSE itself doesn't seem to be able to locate. Can't help but wonder whether it's because a better builtin MSE search facility would find answers more readily and actually decrease traffic.

Comment: But is it indeed "primarily a site for experts to bounce ideas off other experts", or do we want it to be that? The banner you see when you first enter the site without an account says "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math *at any level* and professionals in related fields." I thought the "for experts by experts" site was MathOverflow, not MSE.

Comment: (I myself am a student, and I'm sure most of my questions asked here can be seen by an expert as "struggling with the basics", but nevertheless they were of great value to me and I'd say also to other students who stumble upon the same questions.)

Comment: dxiv but, do you think the the barrage of homework questions we saw this spring were "good" questions though? There are indeed some good homework questions no doubt, if the professor is good, that is why the question was assigned in the first place, because it was a good question. I personally don't think this site is for tutoring students in need of more remedial help though. BUT, it's not just my call. If I am wrong and MSE is a sort of Online TA, then let's scale back EoQS. Otherwise, let's get rid of bad questions faster.

Comment: "Meanwhile, I'm not seeing how the EoQS currently implemented, is changing this." It sounds a bit like you're suggesting there should be a night-and-day difference between the pre-EoQS and current day.  Surely strengthening the ability for the community to moderate out poor quality and to frustrate the creation of poor content is the only hope we have of buoying up site quality. Of course, it is a bit like steering a ship in rough seas: we can't move on a dime, all we can do is to lean into the rudder and do our best to control the heading.

Comment: If i'm mistaken and you are just suggesting some refinements on gaps that are currently not covered by EoQS well then that's good.

Comment: @rschwieb I wish there were *any* discernible difference from EoQS. I can't see any.

Comment: @Mike I'm pretty sure there have been some pretty conspicuous suspensions and retirements of poor content producers, and they are likely not as productive.  And it certainly "feels" like more people are aware enforcement is more active now, even if they view that negatively.  I'm pretty sure some effects are there, although it is certainly not a reversal of the tide.

Comment: I think probably the only way to tangibly curtail poor quality questions would be to have rather exorbitant limitations on who can post at all.  I'm not too excited about the prospects of that...

Comment: @rschwieb I'm not necessarily for more enforcement, I am for smarter enforcement. The net result of what we are doing now w EoQS are question after question of debatable quality, with a long string of comments--in place of a well-written answer written where it is supposed to be--the answer box. The worst of both worlds--still no quality control but now messy flow. Should those questions be allowed to stay? Maybe. But my thought is that if the question is good enough to be answered in the comments, then it is good enough for an answer written in the answer box.

Comment: @Mike This is in line with what i was saying about refinements on gaps. I think it's good you brought it up. Comments should not be a loophole of some sort.

Comment: So what I am suggesting is (a) 3 [or 4 votes as a compromise] to close, *and perhaps most importantly* (b) EoQS being applied to the comments as well as the answers. If we don't want bad questions answered in the answer box, then we certainly don't want them answered in the comments. Those changes would be simple enough to implement.

Comment: @Mike Not sure if we can do anything about the number of votes but we could probably do better on the comments suggestion.  Maybe you could use this to refine your post title. Right now it's kind of both too generic and probably likely to form wrong initial impressions.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure there have been some pretty conspicuous suspensions and retirements of poor content producers...." @rschwieb, I'm pretty sure there have been retirements of excellent content producers. EoQS has its downside, and I'm not convinced that it has been a net positive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that is neither here nor there. We will never be able to stop good content producers who want to leave because the site isn’t run just so.  And if you’re trying to say they were forced out because of EoQS directly then it is questionable that their content was good so…?  My point was to show that there are definitely effects in the intended direction (because it was doubted is that there have been effects at all.). I never claimed that there weren’t side effects or that there is a net gain (although it seems to me there is.)

Comment: @Mike See my answer linked in the previous comment. Then (quoted parts are yours)... 1) Don't think the "*barrage of homework questions we saw this spring*" was different, or worse, this time around vs. previous years - both before and after EoQS. 2) "*don't think this site is for tutoring students*" A good math question does not become a bad one just because a lazy or clueless student asked it while doing their homework. Answering such a question does not only benefit the OP, but also contributes to the "*repository of interesting questions and well-written answers*" for future readers.

Comment: @dxiv 1. I never liked the barrage of homework questions even before EoQS! Some were in fact very good, but too many were pedantic questions poorly formatted asked by the same users over and over. 2. I do agree with you that there are some great questions asked by lazy posters. An answer is still a wonderful thing for MSE. 3. And...as a larger point...I'm not sure how I feel about EoQS in general, but I do not like the way that it is currently implemented now. It does not weed out the chafe [which is what I was focusing on in this thread]. And, IMO it is throwing out too much good wheat.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I cannot disagree with what you are saying. In another thread I talked about how I felt EoQS was throwing out too much of what many of us saw as good content--good answers to questions that were themselves interesting but that were not given the proper context as per MSE Guidelines say. Here tho, I am talking about how EoQS is not stopping what many of us consider to be the low-quality stuff. If we are to stick with EoQS, then surely there is a way to revise the way it is done to make it both more effective at screening out the low-quality stuff, AND keeping the good content.

Comment: I don't see how lowering the number of votes required to close a question, or extending quality standards to comments, will work toward keeping the good content (and keeping the users who provide the good content), Mike.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1. It is pretty rare IME to see a good question with 3 votes to close. 2. If a question is good enough to be answered in the comments, then it is good enough to be answered in the answer box, where it will be easier to see if looked up in the future. And the contrapositive: if a question is not good enough to be answered in the answer box, then it is not good enough to be answered in the comments. The EoQS not taking that into account is just crazy, IMO. [And to answer your question, as I said earlier, this particular thread was more about screening out the low-quality stuff.]

Comment: Mike, if you're concerned about EoQS, why did you answer [the problem statement question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449220/how-to-construct-a-rational-sequence-a-n-such-as-lim-n-to-infty-a-n-co).  While I support what you suggest in your question, my link is hardly a "one off" in terms of the quality of quite a few questions you answer.  Practice what you preach, is all.  One off's of okay, but my link is not a one off.

Comment: Mike Just saying, you need to practice what you preach.

Comment: @Anakhand  That is the spirit of this site, all levels of math.  The issue is NOT how "deep" or brilliant a question is, to remind us all here.  We need questions to follow basic guidelines in the ever-updated FAQ [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C129.4571). That applies to elementary and advanced questions.  The repository sought is of *well-asked questions with well answered answers", whether arithmetic, or algebraic topology, etc.

Comment: @Mike You started your question about MSE as "*a repository of* ***interesting*** *questions and well-written answers*" (and FWIW the official [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) describes its goal as "*a library of detailed answers to* ***every*** *question about math*"). One of the previous comments changed that to "***well-asked*** *questions with well answered answers*". That's, in a nutshell, the EoQS philosophy, and their excuse for punishing the question and the answerers for the sins of the asker.

Comment: @amWhy I agree. The reason I broght that up is because it seems to be in direct opposition with what Mike seems to be saying, which is that it should be "primarily a site for experts to bounce ideas off other experts". I think the problem is in the false dichotomy that if it's not a "site for experts", then the end result cannot be a "repository of interesting questions and well-written answers". (These are all quotes from the first paragraph in the post.)

Comment: Anyways @Anakhand I do owe you an apology. I was not trying to imply that I think good homework questions--as you ask--are bad here. I can see how my original wording came across that way though. I will edit.

Comment: My comments regarding this particular post, I stand by.  But given your subsequent two answers on meta, I think we differ greatly. Just saying that I do not support your criticism of EoQS, or of moderators for engaging in such enforcement of quality. And I doubt you do your best to vote to close poor questions, given that you regularly answer such questions.

Comment: Poor questions are fairly well defined on this site.  For everyone who answers one and then defiantly claim, "I think this is a fine question", in a rant on meta, to keep their rep, and continue to answer low hanging fruit, is merely more gaming.

Comment: Meanwhile, the answer of mine that you had quoted, I had already deleted, *before* you quoted it. When I saw the question was being flagged as a dup I deleted my answer--which by the way, was thoroughly and carefully written [convergence needs to be established first]. There is something about playing gotcha like that in general, no context, that makes my brow furrow. I have 700 [thoroughly-written] answers on here over 4 years. Plenty of those answers are long answers to challenging exercises that took a while to write.

Comment: (Concerning a point raised in the most recent edit of the question) If you think you have a good answer to Question X, but you know that question is a duplicate of Question Y, then the thing to do is to vote to close X as a duplicate while posting your good answer at Question Y (assuming your good answer doesn't duplicate answers already posted to Y).

Comment: @GerryMyerson that actually does make sense.

Comment: I think the problem here is the subjectivity of what is this -interesting question and well-written answer-, but more, the -interesting question-. I've seen good question, and very well answers, and then at some point, a comment from another user, saying practically the opposite.

Comment: @VeronicaR.M. And with EoQS such a difference in opinion is enough to get you banned these days.

Comment: @rschwieb There are (were?) plenty of users here that produced high quality content that few others are capable of, while also producing low quality content that is arguably undesirable. The ratio of high to low quality of course varies from user to user, but it is rarely all good or all bad, as your comment suggests.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. Of course, it was not my intention to suggest their _contributions are all good or all bad_.  But when it comes to influencing their behavior it will produce a sharper dichotomy of ones who conform and ones who rebel. I think there are users who will rebel on a case-by-case basis, but AFAIK we have a good tolerance for that by leaving room for discussion, and they have no reason to leave. Apparently it is only my-way-or-the-highway users that are the ones penalized.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I follow most of your comment. I seem to be missing some context. From my own experience, there is no room for discussion, and no second chance. I was banned for quite a while without any warning or any explanation. I believe I'm far from the only one, but it is very difficult to get any information on how the mass banning happened exactly. If other bans were similar to mine, I understand that most of the prolific users refuse to return.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. Frankly it is hard to swallow that your experience was "without warning, without explanation," and that there was no room for appeal. Even if it was, I doubt it is representative of most users experience. Maybe you need to make sure your email is spelled right or something.  I'm not privy to all that's going on, but it seems to me in the past the transparency has been much higher than what you're describing.

Comment: @rschwieb Of course I have no way of proving this to you; can't prove a negative. The only explanation I got was a canned 'violating site policy'. There was no warning, no discussion, no explanation, nothing pointing me to a specific answer or post. There was room for appeal; I got a textbox in which I could write something to the mods. At this point I decided to step away from MSE though. A quick browse of the website now suggests that quite a few other prolific users had a similar experience.

Comment: @rschwieb There was no communication by email either, by the way. I do get generic MSE mails there on occasion. I did get banned once before when I just joined MSE some 10 years ago. Back then I did get an explanation and a quick chat with a moderator to explain why, that was all good and fine. Not sure why I got the treatment I got; perhaps the mods were/are overworked. Anyway, my point is that the moderation is/was very far from ideal, as some users believe it to be.

Answer (score 5):

(writing this from new user, but I have some experience on this in other SE's and MSE in the recent years)

- I believe that any change that is imposed from "above" will ultimately be difficult to manage and cannot be successful without drastic change in site that would (I bet on that) make this site much less popular and with less visits. And I don't say it is a bad or good thing. I just say it.
- we may like it or not, but what happened to MSE happened organically. and I don't think it is different from other SE sites nor even other open communities where at the beginning we see deep discussions then it disappears.
- The only way that it can be mitigated is an automatic engine to mark question as duplicates. (and then maybe if user posts the same question twice after being duplicated to be banned from site). As we don't have this automatic tool I don't see a practical way to change things.
- It seems one of the functions of MSE is neither "get a repository of interesting questions" nor "online math tutoring site". I got the impression that many people here enjoy answering questions more than they enjoy finding the duplicate.
- The constant steam of low-level questions gives the opportunity (sometimes very rare) for some users to finally post an answer. The community does (as I recall) want the users "to pay back". without this new "duplicate" and low level questions it would be virtually impossible. It might help keep the user here on site to review more questions and to learn.

Comment: The last bullet is the most important in my eyes.  I'm not sure how common it is for MSE users to 'graduate' to MO, but presumably a *continual* maturation of users is what is necessary to sustain the site.

Comment: Either there are enough questions to effectively classify most new questions as duplicates, or there aren't enough and its simply boring to flesh out every slight difference between technically distinct questions.  In the latter case, perhaps assigning extra value for more advanced questioning/answering is necessary.

Comment: Is it still organic when a group of users come along and impose additional rules which were not part of the original stackexchange model? In that case, whatever could possibly happen ever would be organic unless literally forced down by SE itself

Comment: @Aplateofmomos, well, I see what you are saying and in a sense you are right. in another sense those who set the laws are not the only players. rather, most of the players do not set the laws. my point it would be extremely difficult to "educate" the players by few managers/rule setters. if we want the players to search for duplicate before asking, it won't IMO be helpful to do it manually by downvoting and closing questions. it need to be enforced by the structure of the site which implies a drastic change. But hey, maybe I'm just wrong.

Answer (score -3):

There are three main categories of questions which I feel are worth talking about:

1. Conceptually deep questions which can't be answered from standard books
2. Conceptually deep questions which can be answered from standard books
3. Standard problems which come as exercises

In my personal experience, I find it that 90% of mse users can only handle 2. and 3. . There are only handful I met on this site who I really felt" gets it" beyond the book and can answer the type in 1. .

And depending on the subtopic of math, the number of people that maybe capable to answer in this category here is non existent.

Now, for the direction of mse , everything I said in the above paragraph is mostly irrelevant because firstly these questions are in minority, and, I think the people who are capable of writing deep answers won't be attracted more to the site more than they are right now by policy shifts. Infact, I have actually found that the people who answer in 1. often do not engage much in meta.

For 2. and 3., I'll just say let them be to be honest. Students need help and it is certainly valuable to provide a free reliable resource like mse to them. I think we should aim for inclusivty rather than exclusivity at this point.

To begin with mse is already very exclusive because it is not at all simple to use it. Firstly you need an Internet connection, then some command of English, and finally a willingness to learn some mathjax.

Most people don't speak English, and also may not have an Internet connection.

To achieve inclusivity, the website should be made more accessible in some way. I see no future for it if the philosophy is to keep it like some elitist mathematics circle for the English speaking privileged.

---

Now where is it actually going towards? That I believe is unanswerable. Only the future can say.

Comment: Your point about the lack of receptivity of the StackExchange network (I don't know about in general, but at least MO and MSE where I spend most of my time) to non-English questions and answers is well taken, but surely there's not much one can do to remove the requirement of Internet access to be able to use a web site?  (I would think that the requirement to learn Mathjax is not much more onerous than the requirement to learn some math, itself also a prerequisite for useful participation, but maybe I'm biased.)

Comment: Here are some ideas of how things could improve: there would be preformatted question drafts one could use, and, the subject body would auto translate the text written. Some sort of DeepL or Google transfer integration. I'd say mathjax maybe harder than math because mathjax is unlike what most people encounter in school or smthn. The Internet access point, I agree one can't do anything, but my idea was that this site is already tending on the very exclusive side.

Comment: Your last suggestion belongs at meta.se or a separate math.meta question.  But your last comment is not directly related to the question you purport to answer.

Comment: This website is effectively an elitist mathematics circle. Newbie questions get downvoted to oblivion. The learning curve is steep.